# Avoid reCAPTCHA using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

I tried to use Selenium (chromedriver) for webscraping, but always get reCaptchas (around 5-8 in a row) which I have to solve.
When I visit the same website manually with Google Chrome, I don't even get one Captcha.
I don't use headless option...
Is there any solution to avoid these Captchas? Or to get maximum 1-2 Captchas for one request? I mean it's not a problem to solve Captchas for me, but 5-8 in a row takes to much time.

Comment: Check your request headers (specially user-agent).

Comment: Take the hint. They don't want your bots on their site. Respect their wishes and move on.

Answer (score 1):

There are captcha solvers like 2captcha that solve them at around 15-40 seconds each captcha. Captcha was made to detect bots in various shapes and forms and well... that's what it has done. The simple answer is: no, there is no "bypass"
There are some workarounds to avoid the system as a whole such as using an alt-login, like an app that maybe uses a different API. This can be achieved via appium which is similar to selenium, or by using a HTTPRequest library.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. On the net there is a lot of tips that used to work like the suggestion in the comment of using specific headers, especially set the user agent explicitly or slowing down the actions on the page (like clicking) to  mock real user actions. I found all of them not working currently with the newest reCaptcha versions and fell back to using non headless mode and manually solve the captcha before my script takes over and does its magic once I passed the captcha.